# nginx create multiple virtual hosts and ports

Tags: nginx

Is there an easy way in nginx configuration to create multiple virtual hosts?
the port range will be 17100-17200, so its mean the first virtual host will listen to 17100, the second virtual host will listen to port 17101, etc.. without create it one by one of via script?